# SFML: Exception thrown at 0x7767FF05 (ntdll.dll) in Demo.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000004

Tags: c++, sfml, avl-tree

I got a code on github. After I debug it, it gives me an error as shown belowI got a code on github. After I debug it, it gives me an error as shown: Exception thrown at 0x7767FF05 (ntdll.dll) in Demo.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000004.

[img][https://i.imgur.com/y8QG7vk.png[/img]](https://i.imgur.com/y8QG7vk.png%5B/img%5D)

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

#define SFML_NO_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

#pragma warning(suppress : 4996)
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
using namespace std;
using namespace sf;

const int window_w = 1920;
const int window_h = 1080;
float wid = 1920;
int hei = 1080;
float wid_n = 1920;
float hei_n = 1080;
const int l_size = 80;
const int r_size = 30;
const int h_size = 100;
float speed = 50;
float del = 0;
const int scale = 1;
RenderWindow window(VideoMode(window_w, window_h), "AVL Tree");
Font font;
View view;

struct Node {
        int c;
        Node* l, * r;
        int h;
        Node(int cc) :c(cc), h(1), l(NULL), r(NULL) {}
};
typedef Node* Tree;

int get_h(Tree t) {
        if (!t)return 0;
        return t->h;
}

int balancefact(Tree t) {
        if (!t)return 0;
        return get_h(t->r) - get_h(t->l);
}

void update(Tree t) {
        if (!t)return;
        t->h = max(get_h(t->l), get_h(t->r)) + 1;
}

Tree rot_right(Tree t) {
        Tree q = t->l;
        t->l = q->r;
        q->r = t;
        update(t);
        update(q);
        return q;
}

Tree rot_left(Tree t) {
        Tree q = t->r;
        t->r = q->l;
        q->l = t;
        update(t);
        update(q);
        return q;
}

Tree balance(Tree t) {
        if (!t)return t;
        update(t);
        if (balancefact(t) == 2) {
                if (balancefact(t->r) < 0)
                        t->r = rot_right(t->r);
                return rot_left(t);
        }
        if (balancefact(t) == -2) {
                if (balancefact(t->l) > 0)
                        t->l = rot_left(t->l);
                return rot_right(t);
        }
        return t;
}

Tree add(int c, Tree t) {
        if (!t) {
                t = new Node(c);
                return t;
        }
        if (t->c == c)return t;
        if (t->c > c) {
                t->r = add(c, t->r);
        }
        else {
                t->l = add(c, t->l);
        }
        return balance(t);
}

Tree get_min(Tree t) {
        if (!t->l)return t;
        return get_min(t->l);
}

Tree erase(int c, Tree t) {
        if (!t)return t;
        if (t->c > c) {
                t->r = erase(c, t->r);
        }
        else if (t->c < c) {
                t->l = erase(c, t->l);
        }
        else if (t->l && t->r) {
                t->c = get_min(t->r)->c;
                t->r = erase(t->c, t->r);
        }
        else if (t->l)
                t = t->l;
        else
                t = t->r;
        return balance(t);
}

void draw(int x, int y, int c) {
        CircleShape cir;
        Text text;
        text.setFont(font);
        cir.setOrigin(Vector2f(r_size, r_size));
        cir.setRadius(r_size);
        cir.setOutlineColor(Color::Blue);
        cir.setOutlineThickness(3);
        text.setCharacterSize(144);
        text.setString(to_string(c));
        text.setOrigin(text.getLocalBounds().left + text.getLocalBounds().width / 2,
                text.getLocalBounds().top + text.getLocalBounds().height / 2);
        float min_size = min((r_size * 1.5f) / text.getLocalBounds().width, (r_size * 1.5f / 2) / text.getLocalBounds().height);
        text.setScale(Vector2f(min_size, min_size));
        cir.setPosition(x, y);
        text.setPosition(Vector2f(x, y));
        text.setFillColor(Color::Black);

        window.draw(cir);
        window.draw(text);
}

void draw_edg(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
        if (x1 == 0 && y1 == 0)return;
        RectangleShape line(Vector2f(sqrt((x2 - x1) * (x2 - x1) + (y2 - y1) * (y2 - y1)), 6));
        line.setFillColor(Color::Cyan);
        line.setPosition(Vector2f(x1, y1));
        line.rotate(atan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1) * 180.0 / atan2(0, -1));
        window.draw(line);
}

int get(Tree t, int l, int h) {
        if (!t)return 0;
        int r = l;
        if (t->l)
                r = get(t->l, l, h - 1);
        else
                r += l_size * scale;
        if (t->r)
                r = get(t->r, r, h - 1);
        else
                r += l_size * scale;
        if (!t->l && !t->r)
                r += l_size;
        int x_cor = l + (r - l) / 2;
        int y_cor = h * h_size;
        draw(x_cor, y_cor, t->c);
        return r;
}

pair<int, pair<int, int>> get_edg(Tree t, int l, int h) {
        if (!t)return make_pair(0, make_pair(0, 0));
        int r = l;
        pair<int, int> left = make_pair(0, 0);
        pair<int, int> right = make_pair(0, 0);
        if (t->l) {
                pair<int, pair<int, int>> res = get_edg(t->l, l, h - 1);
                r = res.first;
                left = res.second;
        }
        else
                r += l_size * scale;
        if (t->r) {
                pair<int, pair<int, int>> res = get_edg(t->r, r, h - 1);
                r = res.first;
                right = res.second;
        }
        else
                r += l_size * scale;
        if (!t->l && !t->r)
                r += l_size;
        int x_cor = l + (r - l) / 2;
        int y_cor = h * h_size;
        draw_edg(left.first, left.second, x_cor, y_cor);
        draw_edg(right.first, right.second, x_cor, y_cor);
        return make_pair(r, make_pair(x_cor, y_cor));
}

int main() {
        view.reset(FloatRect(0, 0, window_w, window_h));
        srand(time(NULL));
        Tree t = 0;
        Clock clock;
        font.loadFromFile("CyrilicOld.TTF");
        bool change = true;
        int tim = 0;
        int kadr = 0;
        while (window.isOpen()) {
                sf::Event event;
                while (window.pollEvent(event) || change) {
                        float del_tim = clock.getElapsedTime().asMicroseconds();
                        del = del_tim / 4e4;
                        clock.restart();
                        tim += del_tim;
                        kadr++;
                        if (tim > 1e6) {
                                tim -= 1e6;
                                //      cout << kadr << endl;
                                kadr = 0;
                        }
                        if (event.type == Event::Closed || Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Escape)) {
                                window.close();
                        }
                        if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Dash)) {
                                view.zoom(1.03f);
                                speed = speed * 1.03f;
                                wid = wid * 1.03f;
                                change = true;
                        }
                        if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Equal)) {
                                view.zoom(0.97f);
                                speed = speed * 0.97f;
                                wid = wid * 0.97f;
                                change = true;
                        }
                        if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Left)) {
                                view.move(Vector2f(-speed * del, 0));
                                wid += speed * del;
                                change = true;
                        }
                        if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Down)) {
                                view.move(Vector2f(0, speed * del));
                                change = true;
                        }
                        if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Up)) {
                                view.move(Vector2f(0, -speed * del));
                                change = true;
                        }
                        if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Right)) {
                                view.move(Vector2f(speed * del, 0));
                                wid += speed * del;
                                change = true;
                        }
                        if (Mouse::isButtonPressed(Mouse::Left)) {
                                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                                        int key = rand() - rand();
                                        t = add(key, t);
                                }
                                change = true;
                        }
                        if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::A)) {
                                int key;
                                cin >> key;
                                t = add(key, t);
                                change = true;
                        }
                        if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::E)) {
                                int key;
                                cin >> key;
                                t = erase(key, t);
                                change = true;
                        }
                        if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::N)) {
                                view.zoom(wid_n / wid);
                                speed *= wid_n / wid;
                                wid = wid_n;
                        }
                        if (change) {
                                window.setView(view);
                                window.clear(Color(128, 106, 89));
                                get_edg(t, 0, get_h(t));
                                wid_n = get(t, 0, get_h(t));
                                hei_n = get_h(t) * h_size;
                                //change = false;
                                window.display();
                        }
                }
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You initialize your `RenderWindow` object as a global variable. This happens before the start of your program, but there's no fixed order between different global variables. You probably get an error because other variables need to be initialized before you can create `RenderWindow` objects.

In this case, the program tries to write into the address `0x00000004`. A global pointer that `RenderWindow` needs, probably still points to zero and not to a valid memory location. Thus the program crashes.

This problem is often referred to as the *[Static Initialization Order Fiasco](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/siof)*.

The solution in this case is to only initialize `window` after `main()` starts. A possible way to do this is to use `std::optional`:

```
std::optional<RenderWindow> window = std::nullopt;

//...

int main() {
  window = RenderWindow(VideoMode(window_w, window_h), "AVL Tree");
  //...
}
```

You can also use a [singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008019/c-singleton-design-pattern) if you'd like to initialize `window` more implicitly. Personally, I like to use the Meyers singleton in those cases:

```cpp
auto get_window() {
  static RenderWindow window(VideoMode(window_w, window_h), "AVL Tree");
  return window;
}
```